# SSRS Schedule Biweekly

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, scheduling

I have reporting services in sharepoint integrated mode. I have created a schedule with the settings as follows:

```
StartDate        2013-03-01 11:55:00.000
EndDate          NULL
EventType        TimedSubscription
RecurrenceType   4
MinutesInterval  NULL
DaysInterval     NULL
WeeksInterval    2
DaysOfWeek       32
DaysOfMonth      NULL
Month            NULL
MonthlyWeek      NULL
LastRunTime      2013-04-05 11:56:04.670
```

To the best of my understanding this means that it should run At 11:55 AM every Fri of every 2 weeks, starting 3/1/2013.

That is, I expect it should run March 1, March 15, March 29, and April 12. However, as you can see by the LastRunTime, it actually ran on April 5th.

What settings would I use to actually make it run every second Friday?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the schedule is created using the settings above, Reporting Services will look forward from the StartDate to find the next Friday to run on (listed as NextRunTime in the Schedule table). If the StartDate is in the future, that will be NextRunTime. However, if the StartDate is in the past, then NextRunTime will be set to the next available Friday, NOT the Friday two weeks from the StartDate.

What I think has happened in your case is that the schedule was created on a date after 1/3/2013 but before Friday 8/3/2013. This would have set the NextRunTime to Friday 8/3/2013 and so the schedule would have then executed on the following dates:

- 8/3/2013
- 22/3/2013
- 5/4/2013

This would explain your LastRunTime of 5/4/2013. If you look at the Schedule table in ReportServer, I would bet the NextRunTime for this schedule will now (as at 23/4) be 2/5/2013.

To correct this amend your schedule by setting a new Start Date, making sure that this date is before the first Friday that you want the schedule to run on (you can double check this by looking at NextRunTime in the Schedule table).